# Having trouble embedding Unity3d into asp.net mvc web page code and configuration provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game site in asp.net mvc all games are going to be in unity3d

The error I receive when i test my page out is the following;

`"Failed to download data file"`

Here is what is in my .layout.cshtml

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Hippokros</title>
<link href="~/Content/zocial.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Hippokros.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/base_welcome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetUnity() {
        if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
            return unityObject.getObjectById("unityPlayer");
        }
        return null;
    }
    if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") {
        unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "platformer.unity3d", 480, 320);

    }
</script>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@RenderSection("Header", false)
```

Here is the page that I'm placing the div tag that should have the game object embeded.

```
<div id="unityPlayer">
    <div class="missing">
        <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
            <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The game file is in the root project folder. ? I think that's right

and the web.config is setting up the MIME type correctly I think?

```
 <system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</staticContent>
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

I've lost a lot of hours out of dev time working on this problem that i know it's probably just an easy reference or configuration setting change.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

change  `<mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />`
to      `<mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity" />`